# Xcode9 Build failed ['exception' file not found String.h] React-Native-FCM

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode9

I eject my project with ExpoKit and first build in xcode is successed but after I install react-native-fcm, pod 'FirebaseMessaging', run pod install and build in xcode again here are the error.

[image: Error from RNFirMessaging Library]

[image: 'exception' file not found String.h]

Build on Xcode9
IPhone 5s with ios11
react-native-fcm version ^10.0.1

So how can I fix that?